# Need to write list type data from database into different excel sheets

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a list type data returned from the database, and I want to write it into a spreadsheet. The Order By clause in the query has order by A, B, C. I want to write this ordered data into different sheets in the same excel workbook. Please let me know how I can go about doing this. I'm using POI to write data into Excel.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing consultancy.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're able to write to xls file.

So you can define the sheets for example like this:

```
public static void exportToXls()
{
  Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
  ...
  Sheet sheetA = wb.createSheet("sheetA"); 
  Sheet sheetB = wb.createSheet("sheetB");
  Sheet sheetC = wb.createSheet("sheetC");
  ...
  // export the appropriate list to the appropriate sheet
  for (YourObject item : listOrderedByA)
  { 
    rowNo++;
    row = sheetA.createRow((short)rowNo); 
    ...
    // define the columns
  }
  // and similarly for the other lists (ordered by B or C)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply, but what i actually needed was, if my data was ordered by A, B and C, I needed to create a new sheet A, B or C and write corresponding data in it every time my data changed according to the order by clause. There were a lot more issues involved in this too. Finally, what I ended up doing was, I added a variable to my database query thus -

```
select distinct CASE WHEN color = 'Red' THEN 'A' WHEN color = 'Blue' THEN 'B' WHEN color = 'Green' THEN 'C' END AS sheetName, <other fetches from DB>....
```

So, this way, I could check in my code for the change of sheetName and create a new sheet according to that.

Thanks,
Raaz